# Data Set Debug Error

Tags: c#, dataset

Error of IndexOutOfRange -- Can not find table 0 -- here is my code it hits the foreach line and throws the error.  What should I update so this executes?

```
SqlCommand comnd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
StreamWriter strmwr = new StreamWriter(Location);
foreach (DataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows
```

Comment: You are instantiating a new dataset then try to access table[0] ? Your dataset is empty at that point .. You will for sure get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an empty `DataSet` with no tables.  Did you intend to `Fill` the dataset?

```
SqlCommand comnd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SQlDataAdapter(comnd); // create a DataAdapter
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
StreamWriter strmwr = new StreamWriter(Location);   // Not sure what this is for
da.Fill(ds);  // fill the DAtaSet

foreach (DataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows
```

I did not include any `using` statements but would recommend that you wrap all commands and connections in them.

Answer (score 2):

You're never populating the `DataSet` - you're *creating* a SQL command, but never executing it. You're not querying the database at all.

It's not clear whether you really need a `DataSet, to be honest - you could potentially just use a reader returned by [`ExecuteReader`][1]. Personally I'd go in that direction, as I'm not a big fan of`DataSet`. (Alternatively, I'd use an ORM to avoid all this low-level work...)

(Note that you should use `using` statements for your writer, command etc.)

If you really need a `DataSet`, you probably want to look at [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(ds);
// Now your DataSet will have data in it
```

Comment: I would really like to fix that missing backtick but it's just one character.